# What is a non-contiguous directory?

Tags: filesystems, directory

When I run `fsck`, I can see the following line:

```
182 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
```

What kind of directories are the non-contiguous ones? Is there a way to make them to be contiguous somehow. How to find out their name and location?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are talking about fragmented directory blocks. While you create file/ directory , it goes in the parent directory blocks. With time, you create and delete the objects and this blocks become fragmented. This is called non-contiguous directory. There must be feature provided by file system to make them compact . look into the particular file system features.

Comment: There's `-D` option in the ext4 filesystem, but after running fsck with it, the number of the fragmented directories haven't changed.